# How can I get the current time in ISO formatted string with the 'Z' as time designator instead of '+00:00'"?

Tags: datetime, python-3.x, timezone

On Python 3.x `datetime.utcnow().isoformat()` gives no timezone designator and `datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat` gives the `+00:00`. Is there any way to force to use the `Z` (zulu timezone)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The <del>naive</del> straighforward way is

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
datetime.utcnow().isoformat()+'Z' # '2015-06-09T07:17:55.719302Z'
```

`datetime.utcnow()` returns a naive `datetime` on UTC , `isoformat` won't add any timezone because there is none in the naive datetime, and then we add manually the `'Z'` because we know that it's actually in the UTC / Zulu timezone

or if you happen to have a timezone aware `datetime` on UTC already you can just drop the timezone (make a copy of the `datetime` first) and the do the `.isoformat()+'Z'`.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
datetime.now(timezone.utc).replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat()+'Z'
# '2015-06-09T07:17:55.719302Z'
```

If the timezone aware `datetime` is not on UTC then you need to bring it to the UTC timezone first.

```
from datetime import datetime,timezone
from dateutil.tz import tzutc
datetime.now(tzoffset("BRST", -10800)).astimezone(tzutc()).replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat()+'Z'
# '2015-06-09T08:14:02.861058Z'
```

Comment: note: "naive" way is not naive. It is the right way in this case (readability, performance). You might mean the way that uses a naive datetime object.